# CompletableFuture recursion for reliability

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming, java-8, future

This is very basic recursion for `CompletableFuture`, I want to make reliable system so each time got exception to restart process again, I'm believing it has too much issues and want to get your feedback about it

```
private CompletableFuture<?> recursion() {
return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    //code here
    }).handleAsync((v, th) -> {
        if (th != null)
            return this.recursion();
        else
            return v;
    });
}
```

Edit1:

```
int tries =5;
private CompletableFuture<?> recursion() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    //code here
    }).handleAsync((v, th) -> {
        if (th != null && tries-- > 0){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return this.recursion();
        }else
            return v;
    });
}
```

Edit2:
cleaning code as the return  `CompletableFuture<?>` has no need so hanged it to be returning `void` considering @Holger comment and using AtomicInteger for tries

```
AtomicInteger tries =5;
private void recursion() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    //code here
    }).whenCompleteAsync((v, th) -> {
        if (th != null && ( tries.getAndDecrement() > 0 ) ){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.recursion();
        });
}
```

please send me you feedback,I'm arguing but really appreciate it.

Comment: You should also take into the fact that using recursion might blow up with a `StackOverflowError` or an infinite loop.

Comment: yes I'm considering it actually thought to make number of tries and sleep between each try.

Comment: Such things already exist but I suggest you take a look at `rxjava`. There is also `asyn-cretry` which is nice: https://github.com/nurkiewicz/async-retry

Comment: I'm trying to do it with pure java, I already made implementation for the reactive- streams here https://github.com/bassemZohdy/simple-reactive-streams but want to do this with java CompletableFuture

Comment: I got it from start but let me ask what is side effect of it, rather than making generic type signature meaningful, which is considerable point.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, simply retrying an operation when an exception occurs, without ever dealing with the exception to analyze the reason of the failure, is far away from creating a reliable system.

Nevertheless, if you want to implement retries, your code fails to do this correctly.

Your code happens to get accepted by the compiler because you use an action which doesn’t produce a value and return a `CompletableFuture<?>`. This hides the problems with your code:

The bifunction passed to `handleAsync` is supposed to provide the result value but you are calling `this.recursion()` which produces a `CompletableFuture<?>`. The compiler doesn’t mind that in the non-exceptional case `v` is returned, as `Void` and `CompletableFuture<?>` have a common super type, `Object`, so the entire method is effectively returning a `CompletableFuture<Object>` which is compatible with the return type `CompletableFuture<?>`.

If you declared the return type as `CompletableFuture<Void>`, the logical error became recognizable immediately: in the exceptional case you are launching another asynchronous operation but since you are not checking it’s result but just returning a `CompletableFuture<?>`, which is then treated as `Object`, the caller will never notice whether the retry (or subsequent retries) failed. The caller will always receive a `CompletableFuture<?>` which reports a success, holding either `(Void)null` or a `CompletableFuture<?>` as result value.

Generally, you shouldn’t use recursion for a repetition. There is no reason to do so. Let’s demonstrate the logic with an action which returns a value:

```
CompletableFuture<String> performAsyncAction() {
    Supplier<String> action=() -> {
        if(Math.random()>0.2)
            throw new IllegalStateException("simulated failure");
        return "value implying success";
    };
    int retries=5;
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try { return action.get(); }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            for(int i=0; i<retries; i++) try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return action.get();
            } catch(Throwable next) { t.addSuppressed(next); }
            throw t;
        }
    });
}
```

It’s easy to adapt to use a `Runnable`, `runAsync` and `CompletableFuture<Void>`.

---

Update: if you just want to schedule a retry without giving a feedback to the initiator, you may implement it without blocking a thread by waiting for the delay to elapse:

```
static ScheduledExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

static void performAsyncAction(Runnable r, int tries, long delay, TimeUnit u) {
    if(tries>0)
        e.execute(()-> { try { r.run(); } catch(Throwable t) {
            e.schedule(()->performAsyncAction(r, tries-1, delay, u), delay, u);
        }});
}
```

This uses recursion as it settles on lambda expressions. The same would work without recursion if you use an inner class:

```
static ScheduledExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

static void performAsyncAction(Runnable r, int tries, long delay, TimeUnit u) {
    if(tries>0)
        e.execute(new Runnable() {
            int left = tries;
            public void run() {
                try { r.run(); } catch(Throwable t) {
                    if(--left > 0) e.schedule(this, delay, u);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: you code meaning that the thread will be locked inside for loop for all tries and I do not want to do so, I understand your points but as I'm telling it is basic, was thinking to get from user which exception to retry on.

Comment: The loop runs inside an asynchronous operation, i.e. a distinct thread. There is no point in detaching the iterations into individual threads which will then wait for each other as each `handleAsync` creates a *dependent* operation. In fact, the underlying implementation might be smart enough to recognize that the stages depend on each other and reuse the thread of the previous stage for the next one. But if not, you are creating up to `retries` number of additional threads for no benefit. You can’t change the sequential nature of “try again if the previous attempt failed”.

Comment: wait with handleAsync ?? not it is not waiting as it is releasing the first thread and in my case when running it with Thread pool actually thread is released and reused by the same operation, but using for loop is not releasing thread at all, in other words if your CompletableFuture is not done not meaning that resources are not released.

Comment: @Bassem Reda Zohdy: what’s the point of that discussion? Besides that your originally code doesn’t work anyway, it will release and reuse one thread in the best case while my solution will use one thread throughout the operation. Where’s the difference? It means that in both cases the entire operation uses one thread. But your attempt makes it more complicated and there is no guaranty that one stage will use the same thread the previous has just released…

Comment: 1st my code is working and doing what I want it to do check this Gist for more details https://gist.github.com/bassemZohdy/f100789df84f7fa7a77c, the point of this discussion that to make it better and get issues which others can tell me about, the different is in your solution thread is locked all time and resources not released tell all tries are done including 5 times of Thread.sleep, yes you are using one thread but block it all time including sleep time in my case it is released and reused and sleep time is out.

Comment: First of all, your solution is only working if you ignore the fact that the returned `CompletableFuture<?>` does not reflect whether the retries succeeded. If you that’s what you want, you shouldn’t return a future creating a wrong impression.

Comment: Second, your “release and reuse” is just a disguise, you are still always using one thread, possibly minus a few nanoseconds. But if you sleep inside an action you *always* block a thread, regardless of how you obfuscate the fact. And the sleep time is the time that matters. If you want to avoid it when using a `CompletableFuture`, you have to understand how [`ManagedBlocker`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker.html) work. But generally, `CompletableFuture` is the wrong tool for that kind of job.

Comment: Thanks @Holger I updated my code to return void now, and reading more about ManagedBlocker I did not use it before, I really appreciate your answer and comments, but still researching for a better way.